# Use App Password to Authenticate with PowerShell PnP

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, authentication, pnp-powershell, multifactor-authentication

Suppose you have a tenant with MFA enabled.
The same tenant allows users to create private app passwords like on the screenshot below.

[image]

**Question**:

- Is it possible to use this app password to authenticate against a site using PowerShell PnP?
- When using this app password, does this app have the same permissions as my account?

This is my attempt to authenticate with the app password, to give you an idea what I am trying to do:

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you'd want to do this? App Passwords should be disabled as they're a security end-run around Modern Auth. If you need to automate a script, use a client ID/secret with registered application in Azure AD.

Comment: The reason I am asking the question is to learn how this works. I work with many clients and all of them have this feature disabled. However, yesterday I have noticed that this feature is available in one tenant with MFA. I thought why not try to use it. Azure App registrations work great, but it's really hard to get from large clients. I can only dream to get it approved in a bank, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**.

You can use app password to authenticate SharePoint Online site using PowerShell PnP.

Hit below URL:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com
```

It will open a pop-up like below where you can pass user username and app password:

[image]

And, If you are using:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com -PnPO365ManagementShell
```

> This will authenticate you using the PnP O365 Management Shell Multi-Tenant application. A browser window will have to be opened where you have to enter a code that is shown in your PowerShell window.

You will get the code in below format

```
WARNING: To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code XXXXXXXXX to authenticate.
```

And Yes, this will have the same permissions as your account.

**Update from Comments**:

Try using below code to avoid pop-up asking for App Password:

```
$username = "user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = "XXXXXXXXX"

$encpassword = convertto-securestring -String $password -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $encpassword
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com -Credentials $cred
```

Comment: Thank you, Ganesh. Is it possible to use the app password without a popup?

Comment: Yes, check the updated answer.

Comment: Seems this has changed and app password do not work anymore. Any more ideas? :|

Comment: Check this [documentation](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Connect-PnPOnline.html) for all authentication cmdlets. Try using `Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://contoso.sharepoint.com" -UseWebLogin` or `Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://contoso.sharepoint.com" -Interactive`