# PNP script to get all subsite in a single site collection, please with MFA for SP online

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, pnp-powershell, authentication, sub-site

Found plenty of scripts but they are not with MFA. MFA is a standard now, do not understand why people insist of creating scripts not considering that.

Can someone help?

Comment: Do you need unattended script or attended? For attended you can still use interactive flag?

Comment: No idea what those things mean, I need to run the script to get subsites to a site that should not contain more than 200 and either get the result on the screen or in a CSV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this PnP PowerShell script for getting all subsites in a SharePoint site collection:

```
$siteUrl = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/marketing"
 
Try {
    # Connect to SharePoint online site
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -Interactive
  
    # Get all subsites in SharePoint Online site using PnP PowerShell
    $subsites = Get-PnPSubWeb -Recurse -IncludeRootWeb
      
    # Loop through each web in site collection
    ForEach($web in $subsites)
    {
        Write-host $web.Url
    }
}
catch {
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}
```

Check below threads for more information about authentication with MFA:

1. [Use App Password to Authenticate with PowerShell PnP](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277143/use-app-password-to-authenticate-with-powershell-pnp/277151#277151)
2. [The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/275517/the-sign-in-name-or-password-does-not-match-one-in-the-microsoft-account-system/275520#275520)

**Documentation**: [Get-PnPSubWeb](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPSubWeb.html)

Comment: ok, this works, once i see the list on the screen, any tip to copy/paste it outside?

Comment: Select/mark the output and use Ctrl + C **OR** You can export results to CSV, use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv? Here are few other ways: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543578/copy-text-from-a-windows-cmd-window-to-clipboard

Answer (score 0):

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://contoso.sharepoint.com" -UseWebLogin
```

OR

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://contoso.sharepoint.com" -Interactive
```

Try either of these and then execute your commands. You should be prompted for credentials and MFA details.

Connecting to the site is first step. Once you have connection established. You can execute command below which gives all subsites for given site.

```
Get-PnPSubWeb  -Recurse -IncludeRootWeb
```

More details here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/499551/unable-to-connect-to-pnp-powershell-for-sharepoint

https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPSubWeb.html

Comment: I need the complete script of getting all the subsites to a site with MFA connection, I was able to find that myself

Comment: Sure. added more details. Little humility will help though.